# how to split the string in java

Tags: java, string, split

how to split the string in java in Windows?
 I used 
     Eg.

```
String directory="C:\home\public\folder";
String [] dir=direct.split("\");
```

I want to know how to split the string in eg. 
In java, if I use `"split("\")"` , there is syntax error.

thanks

Comment: there is a syntax error in the very first line, probably meant: `String directory="C:\\home\\public\\folder";`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`split()` function in Java accepts regular expressions. So, what you exactly need to do is to escape the backslash character twice:

```
String[] dir=direct.split("\\\\");
```

One for Java, and one for regular expressions.

Comment: Is this code's result must be an array like this : [c:][home][public][folder] ???

Answer (score 7):

The syntax error is caused because the sing backslash is used as [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in Java.

In the Regex `'\'` is also a escape character that why you need escape from it either.

As the final result should look like this `"\\\\"`.

But You should use the `java.io.File.separator` as the split character in a path.

```
String[] dirs = dircect.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator));
```

thx to John

Comment: On Wndows, `File.separator` (<- you made a typo) is a regex-meta char, causing an exception to be thrown at runtime.

Comment: No `if` statement necessary: `dircect.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator))`, which is already suggested by John, so instead of just copying (correct) answers, mind as well delete this answer, IMO.

Comment: While I was answering the Johns answer does not contain that information, besides he do not used the File.separator. So this is not a copied.

Comment: Well, then you copied it from me and John. But suit yourself, just leave all the duplicate information here.

Comment: Only thing that i've used is Pattern.quote. Rest is not copied. Show me another answer where the separator is mentioned ? Instead of criticizing people you could show them that they are doing wrong, but even you before John answer did not though about that Pattern.quote. Ive edited the answer before your lazy comment but still you can stick to your theory that everything is copied and you have been harm in this procedure. What ever for my point of view. Bye ;-).

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
direct.split("\\\\");
```

Once for a java string and once for the regex.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape it.

```
String [] dir=direct.split("\\\\");
```

---

**Edit**: or Use [Pattern.quote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
 String [] dir=direct.split(Pattern.quote("\\"))
```

Comment: Split takes a regular expression. This pattern will not compile (in runtime).

Answer (score 2):

Please, don't split using file separators.

It's highly recommended that you get the file directory and iterate over and over the parents to get the paths. It will work everytime regardless of the operating system you are working with.

Try this:

```
String yourDir = "C:\\home\\public\\folder";
File f = new File(yourDir); 
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
while ((f = f.getParentFile()) != null) {
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: It took me a little time to understand what was the discussion in the first paragraph. Why not say directly 'Please, don't split using the file separators' and then continue the otherwise clear answer..

Answer (score 0):

I guess u can use the StringTokenizer library

```
String directory="C:\home\public\folder"; 
String [] dir=direct.split("\");
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(directory, '\');
while(token.hasTokens()
{
    String s = token.next();
}
```

This may not be completely correct syntactically but Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String[] array = dir.split("[\\\\/]",-1) ;
 String arrval="";

   for (int i=0 ;i<array.length;i++)
      {
        arrval=arrval+array[i];

      }
   System.out.println(arrval);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because of the backslash. A backslash is used to escape characters. Use

```
split("\\")
```

to split by a backslash.

Comment: Split takes a regular expression. This pattern will not compile (in runtime).

Comment: That will throw a `PatternSyntaxException` at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] a1 = "abc bcd"
String[] seperate = a1.split(" ");
String finalValue = seperate[0];
System.out.pritln("Final string is :" + finalValue);
```

This will give the result as **abc**

Comment: please read the question carefully before answering. The question was about an issue causing by a backslash sign, not about how to split strings in general. ;)

Answer (score -2):

`split("\\")`     A backlash is used to escape.

Comment: That will throw a PatternSyntaxException at compile time.