# How to split directory path components in string in java

Tags: java, string, file, directory, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to split the string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174182/how-to-split-the-string-in-java)

```java
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
File[] roots = fsv.getRoots();
for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++)
{
  System.out.println("Root: " + roots[i]);
}
System.out.println("Home directory: " + fsv.getHomeDirectory());
```

Root: C:\Users\RS\Desktop
Home directory: C:\Users\RS\Desktop

I want cut the root or Home Directory components like 
String C, Users, RS, Desktop

Comment: `String.split()` will help u. Refer to Javadoc for String functions

Answer (score 12):

I'd rather not succumb to the temptation of using split ona file name, when java has its own cleaner, cross-platform functions for path manipluation.

I think this basic pattern works from java 1.4 and onward:

```
    File f = new File("c:\\Some\\Folder with spaces\\Or\\Other");
    do {
        System.out.println("Parent=" + f.getName());
        f = f.getParentFile();
    } while (f.getParentFile() != null);
    System.out.println("Root=" + f.getPath());
```

Will output:

```
    Path=Other
    Path=Or
    Path=Folder with spaces
    Path=Some
    Root=c:\
```

You probably want to use f.getCanonicalPath or f.getAbsolutePath first, so it also works with relative paths.

Unfortunately, this needs f.getPath for the root and f.getName for the other parts, and i create the parts in backward order.

UPDATE: You can compare f with fsv.getHomeDirectory() while scanning upward, and break when it turns out you were in a subdirectory of your home folder.

Comment: You can split on a platform independent level: String[] subDirs = path.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator));

Answer (score 6):

In the light of user844382 answer, this is the platform safe way for splitting the path:

```
 String homePath = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 System.out.println(homePath);
 System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(homePath.split(Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getProperty("file.separator")))));        
}
```

On linux it outputs:

```
/home/isipka
[, home, isipka]
```

On windows it outputs:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\linski\Desktop
[C:, Documents and Settings, linski, Desktop]
```

If you omit the [Matcher.quoteReplacement()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29) method call, the code will fail on windows. This method handles the escaping of special characters like "\" ([file separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) on windows) and "$".

Answer (score 3):

You could use java.nio.file.Path for this:

```
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
File[] roots = fsv.getRoots();
for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++)
{
  System.out.println("Root: " + roots[i]);
  Path p = roots[i].toPath();
  for (int j=0; j < p.getNameCount(); j++)
     System.out.println(p.getName(j));
}
System.out.println("Home directory: " + fsv.getHomeDirectory());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
File[] roots = fsv.getRoots();
for (int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Root: " + roots[i]);
    for (String s : roots[i].toString().split(":?\\\\")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
System.out.println("Home directory: " + fsv.getHomeDirectory());
```

Comment: what if i want result as string1 = C

Comment: @rohitarora What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try using regex split `root.split(":?\\\\")`

Answer (score 1):

A solution that is different than the others would be to get the name from the File API:

```
File file = roots[i];
while (file != null) {
  if (file.getName().length() > 0) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
  } else {
    System.out.println(file.getPath().substring(0, 1));
  }
  file = file.getParentFile();
}
```

This solution returns the path in the reversed order, so you will have to do some small changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the String.split() method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

It takes regular expressions when splitting, so it's possible to do some really advanced stuff. For you splitting by `\\`might do it.

Since `\` adds functionality to regular expressions, we need to mark it as a character rather than the "regex operator". That explains the double .